# Is it possible to attach custom sources to the Windows 8 Notifications?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, notifications, rss

Using Windows 8.1 desktop, you may have notifications enabled in the top right of your screen, these can be enabled on incoming mail (Outlook), instant message (Skype) or appointment (Calendar).

Is it possible to attach custom sources to those notifications? I would be looking for a RSS reader for example then.

Generally I don't like the Modern UI, but I think such a feature would be useful to have enabled.

I know this is possible with other RSS reader tools, but I think it's nicer if it is possible directly in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in RSS reader in Windows 8. You will have to use a third party app.